# Store predefined Layers for SDL Renderer

Tags: c++, sdl

I've been stuck now for quite a while on this problem:
My code looks something like that

```
enum class LayerType {Foreground, Terrain, Background, Target};

class Texture
{
private:
    ...
    Texture       * target;
    LayerType       targetLayer;
    ...
public:
    ...
    Texture       & getTarget();
    void            setTarget(Texture & texture);
    ...
};

class Renderer
{
private:
    ...
    map<GAME::LayerType, Texture> layers;
    ...
public:
    ...
    void                drawTexture(Texture & texture);
    ...
};
```

When the constructor for the renderer is called i set for each enum type an entry in the map, so each layer has its own texture (and the targetLayer is set to LayerTypeTarget). The idea is it that i dont have to draw all textures in the correct order, but on the correct target texture.

The present function of the renderer looks like this.

```
void Renderer::present()
{
    this->setRendererEmptyTarget();
    for(map<LayerType, Texture>::reverse_iterator it = this->layers.rbegin(); it != this->layers.rend(); it++)
    {
        this->drawTexture(it->second);
    }
    SDL_RenderPresent(this->ren);
}
```

and the drawing function like this:

```
void Renderer::drawTexture(Texture & texture)
{
    if(texture.getTargetLayer() != LayerType::Target)
    {
        this->setRendererTarget(this->layers.find(texture.getTargetLayer())->second);
    }
    SDL_RenderCopy(this->ren, texture.getTexture(), NULL, NULL);
}
```

The problem is that all textures are drawn in the order of the function calls and not in the order of the target textures. I think that the problem might be the missing referencing for the target textures.

**EDIT:**

The left image shows how it should look like and the right shows how it actually looks:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gKXm.jpg

The code for the left image:

```
// s1, s2 are surfaces
// the targetTexture contains the sdl flags for a target texture
Texture targetTexture = Texture(this->renderer, LayerType::Target);
Texture t1 = Texture(this->renderer, s1, LayerType::Menu);
Texture t2 = Texture(this->renderer, s2, LayerType::Terrain);

while(running)
{
    this->renderer.setTarget(targetTexture);
    this->renderer.drawTexture(t1);
    this->renderer.setEmptyTarget();
    this->renderer.drawTexture(t2);
    this->renderer.present();
}
```

And the code for the right image:

```
// s1, s2 are surfaces
Texture t1 = Texture(this->renderer, s1, LayerType::Menu);
Texture t2 = Texture(this->renderer, s2, LayerType::Terrain);

while(running)
{
    this->renderer.drawTexture(t1);
    this->renderer.drawTexture(t2);
    this->renderer.present();
}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, your idea is that you have a drawing algorithm where you draw certain layer types together? e.g. first all background textures and such?

Comment: That is correct. First all Terrain tiles will be drawn to a terrainlayer then the trees, and so on. After that all texture layers will be drawn to the screen.

Comment: But then, in the member variable `map<GAME::LayerType, Texture> layers` there is at most one LayerType stored and accordingly only one Texture per LayerType. I think you want multiple textures per layer type, no? So perhaps you want an `std::map<LayerType, std::vector<Texture>>` or something like that.

Comment: The layers that are stored in this map are meant to be the targets (foreground, background, etc. ...) so when the `drawTexture`method is called, the renderer target is set to this texture target. In fact the texture will be drawn on to another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with pointers. I replaced

```
map<GAME::LayerType, Texture> layers;
```

with

```
map<GAME::LayerType, Texture*> layers;
```

So, i have now my reference :-)